# Forecasting future quarters using SMA or EMA in r by group

Tags: r, time-series, forecasting

I am trying to forecast using the SMA function or EMA function (TTR Package https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/TTR/versions/0.24.2/topics/SMA) in r for time series. Here is an example of the data frame I am working with:

```
Product<- c("Watch","Watch","Watch","Phone","Phone","Phone","Computer","Computer","Computer")
Region<- c("US","US","US","China","China","China","US","US","US")
Quarter<- c("03/31/2020","06/30/2020","09/30/2020","03/31/2020","06/30/2020","09/30/2020","03/31/2020","06/30/2020","09/30/2020")
Amount<-c(1000,2000,2100,500,600,620,100,110,105)
df<-data.frame(Product,Region,Quarter,Amount)
```

How can I use the sma function or ema to forecast a select amount of quarters in r? I was able to do something similar with the auto.arima function, but the forecast was way off so I want to just implement a simple moving average or an ema. I also want to keep the data frame in the same format, so I just want to add extra observations or even convert it to wide with the new columns being the quarter with the amount, either is fine.

Auto.Arima Example:

```
test1<-df %>% dplyr::group_by(Product,Region) %>% do(data.frame(amount_2 = forecast(auto.arima(.$Amount)$mean, h=3)))
```

Comment: can you specify the packages used

Comment: I added the package!

Comment: In the data showed, you have 1  observation per group for Product, Region

Comment: Oops my bad, I subsetted the data let me fix that